# Banner in Wordpress

Tags: headers

I'm trying to add an ad banner to my wordpress homepage (in the header) plus a separate ad banner for all other pages (in the header). I did get the banner up for just the homepage but I'm trying to figure the code to complete this issue.

`<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?><div id="banner">my content</div><?php } ?>`

How can I get another ad banner on all other pages/posts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?><div id="banner">my content</div><?php } else { ?><div id="banner">not-home banner/div><?php } ?>
```